# Installing APE project on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, comet, osx-leopard, ape

I would like to test Ajax Push on my local server and I found Ape-progect but I need help to install and configure it.  Honestly I don't know how to start...

Can someone help me  to install and configure APE project on Mac OS (snow leopard)?

Which version I have to install on Mac OS (10.7)? http://www.ape-project.org/download/APE_Complete_Package.html

Thanks!

Comment: 1) http://www.ape-project.org/download/APE_Complete_Package.html

Answer (score 0):

Download from github in development source.
Untar the package. Open the terminal, go into the directory of APE and type >> sh build.sh

APE will install and then you can go to the bin directory and after typing ./aped the server will start